# Perhaps I should go into pest control

Tags: riddle, video-games

Some say that I'm a drunkard - no!
I only need my morning joe
to get me up and off the ground.
Until then, please don't stick around.

But when I'm up, I'm such a friend!
Wise tips and lessons, I will lend
to strangers who are passing through
and in need of a pal or two.

And that's all, folks - or so I thought,
'til one adventurer, they sought
to hear my sage advice once more
ere heading for a distant shore.

For what purpose, I do not know,
though I've had dreams since then, which show
some fearsome beasts beyond compare
and garbled beings from who-knows-where.

**Who am I?**

Comment: Why video games? Is that a hint?

Comment: @Duck Yes, I would take that tag seriously.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with Ready player one?

Comment: No films are involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You are the Old Man in Viridian City from the Pokemon games for Gameboy.

Some say that I'm a drunkard - no!
I only need my morning joe
to get me up and off the ground.
Until then, please don't stick around.

> The Old Man in Viridian city can be found lying on the ground outside, blocking the path for the player until he or she takes care of Professor Oak's business

But when I'm up, I'm such a friend!
Wise tips and lessons, I will lend
to strangers who are passing through
and in need of a pal or two.

> After he's had his coffee, he apologizes for his behavior and proceeds to teach the player how to use a Pokeball to catch Pokemon

And that's all, folks - or so I thought,
'til one adventurer, they sought
to hear my sage advice once more
ere heading for a distant shore.

> The player came along to hear the wise Old Man's tips before embarking on an epic journey across the island continent, seeing shores along the way.

For what purpose, I do not know,
though I've had dreams since then, which show
some fearsome beasts beyond compare
and garbled beings from who-knows-where.

> The player's conversation with the Old Man doesn't go into detail about the player's journey, but perhaps he overheard second-hand stories about the Unknown No.s, which are a garbled data game bug that manifests as a Pokemon around Cinnabar Island, and then dreamed about them while sleeping in the middle of the path as he so often does.

Comment: This is definitely it, and I see how it fits all the clues, but perhaps this answer could be improved by explaining the reasoning. (the coffee/alcohol disparity between localisations, the Missingno. glitch)

Comment: Yes, please explain how this answer addresses each part of the riddle.

Comment: @CGreen done. Sorry, I was excited that I knew the answer so I just answered!

Comment: Technically, the “distant shore” references the shore of one particular island, Cinnabar Island, but I appreciate your completed answer and it is correct!